# Promise.all() then is getting called before the promise resolve() is complete

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, restify, formidable

I am new to node. Trying to build a service which will call AWS to load multiple images and return the AWS keys to the client. Here, I am using Promise all to complete all the AWS call and get the AWS keys and then return the bunch of keys to the client.

But I am surprised, the Promise.all() then() is getting called before the Promise resolve(). Need help badly. Pardon me for my bad node code.

```
server.post('/photo', function (req, res, next) {

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    var result = [];

    form.on('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {
        console.log('err');
    });

    form.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('err',err);
    });

    form.on('end', function() {
        console.log('ended!!!!', arguments);
    });

    form.on('aborted', function() {
        console.log('aborted', arguments);
    });

    var urls = processAllFiles(form);
    Promise.all([urls]).then(function(result) {
        console.log('[][][]', urls);
    }).catch(function (err){
        console.log(err);
    });
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log('am at parse');
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write('received upload:\n\n', urls);
        res.end('received files:\n\n '+util.inspect(files));
    })
    return;

}) 

function processAllFiles(form) {
    var result = [];
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
    {   try{
        form.onPart = function (part) {
            const params = {
                Bucket: 'xxxxx',
                Key: uuidv4() + part.filename
            };

            var upload = s3Stream.upload(params);

            upload.on('error', function (error) {
                console.log('errr', error);
            });
            upload.on('part', function (details) {
                console.log('part', details);
            });
            upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
                result.push(details);
                console.log('uploaded', result);
            })
            part.pipe(upload);
        }
        resolve(result);
    } catch(exception){
        reject('error');
    }

    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
upload.on('uploaded', function (details) {
            result.push(details);
            console.log('uploaded', result);
            resolve(result);
        })
```

I think you should put resolve in async function's callback

Answer (score 0):

The processAllFiles function is only returning 1 promise, so Promise.all() is unnecessary. You can directly do
`processAllFiles.then(...)`
 
Note that Node.js is asynchronous, so the order that you call things may not resolve in the order that you expect (contrary to synchronous calls).

Comment: Ok, thanks for you comment. I removed Promise.All() and called directly processAllFiles.then(...) still I see then() is getting executed before resolve().